# publishing a web application with advanced precompile options set to merge throwing an issue due to custom attribute in AssemblyInfo

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, publish, webdeploy

I have a quite strange error.  I'm trying to precompile an Asp.Net application.  From the **Advanced Precompile Options**, I chose to `Merge all pages and control outputs to a single assembly`, and typed in a name for the assembly.

If I tick this option, I get an error during publish due to a custom attribute in `AssemblyInfo.cs`. Errors copied below:

```
Error   239 The type or namespace name 'CS' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)    Properties\AssemblyInfo.cs  4   7   Deploy
Error   240 The type or namespace name 'MyAssembly' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)    Properties\AssemblyInfo.cs  40  12  Deploy
Error   241 The type or namespace name 'MyAssemblyAttribute' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)   Properties\AssemblyInfo.cs  40  12  Deploy
```

If I remove the attribute, it works.  If I leave the attribute, but do not tick `Merge all pages and control outputs to a single assembly` but chooose `Do Not merge`, it works.

Any ideas why is this?

Also, does it offer any performance benefit between the `Do not merge` and `Merge all pages and control outputs to a single assembly` option?

I am using .Net 4.5 and VS2012 latest update.

Comment: Too bad no one ever answered this question.  I'm running into a similar issue in Visual Studio 2017.